# Beginner setup of a nrf52840 dongle

Tags: nrf52, openthread

I bought a nordic nrf52840 dongle and I am trying to program it using the nRF connector. I have followed this tutorial https://electronut.in/nrf52840-thread/, and after I create the application.hex I need to flash it in the dongle. However when I try to write this new .hex I have the following error:

[nrf-connector-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDrpE.png)

I know that I need a bootloader and a SoftDevice, and that probably I need to merge them using some mergehex tool. I can't understand how to create this bootloader and SoftDevice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use nRF Connect with USB bootloader you have to shift your application RAM/FLASH regions. RAM should start at 0x20000008 and FLASH should start at 0x1000. That's all you have to do.